# Get First row/id & Last row/id of total inserted result set, instead of only last id/row. SQL,PHP,Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

```
 function storeReachout($reachoutInfo)
{


     $result = $this->db->insert('tbl_youtube',$reachoutInfo);
//   $Frow = $result->first_row('array');
//   $Lrow = $result->last_row('array'); 
//   $data = aray($result,$Frow,$Lrow);
//   $result_id = $this->db->insert_id();
     return $result;
}
```

Above is the code to insert data in DB, if I inserted like 30 records I want to know the first inserted row/id and last row/id. This way I can get a lower limit of ID and upper limit of ID so after I can send emails to in-between IDS.

Comment: I tried the above methods $result gives null because the insert query returns bool value and  $result->first_row and $result->last_row can't work on it. The  $this->db->insert_id only gives the last inserted id.

Comment: After posting I found a way to get the first & last inserted ID, I made a foreach loop in my controller to insert each record in a loop and return last_id from my model function and save that last_id in an array in my controller every time the loop iterate it stores a record in DB and gets the last_id and save that last_id in an array. When the loop completes its iteration we will get all the saved IDS from DB in my Array.

Answer (score 0):

After posting I found a way to get the first & last inserted ID, I made a foreach loop in my controller to insert each record in a loop and return last_id from my model function and save that last_id in an array in my controller every time the loop iterate it stores a record in DB and gets the last_id and save that last_id in an array. When the loop completes its iteration we will get all the saved IDS from DB in my Array.